# Послать значение в выполнить из VBA

Tags: windows, excel, access, vba

Как я могу через VBA послать значение в "Выполнить" ?

Например, значение может как Web-ссылкой на картинку, так и локальной ссылкой на картинку и я , что бы не заморачиваться, хотел бы это предоставить "Выполнить".

Answer (score 1):

При вызове использовать команду `Shell(pathname[,windowstyle])`, где

`pathname` - "`explorer.exe`" + " " + `<Web-ссылка на картинку>` либо `<Локальная ссылка на картинку>`;

`windowsstyle`- параметр окна в котором запускается "`explorer.exe`" (минимизированное, открытое на весь монитор и т.п.).

Пример:

1. Имеем две ссылки на графические файлы в таблице `MS Excel`

[image: Файл MS Excel]

2. Вызываем по `F8` макрос `ShowPic`
   [image: Вызов макроса]
3. Код макроса

   ```
   Sub ShowPic()
       Dim StrtApp As String
       ' Значение активной ячейки
       StrtApp = ActiveCell.Value
       ' Формируем выражение и выполняем
       RsltCmd = Shell("explorer.exe" + " " + StrtApp, vbNormalFocus)
   End Sub
   ```
4. В результате `explorer.exe` в зависимости от значения ячеек (`StrtApp`) в соответствии с настройками ОС запустит приложение для отображения графического файла.